# Custom fields in a managed package

Tags: managed-package, custom-field

If you create custom fields in a managed package, will that field be lost when the package is updated?

Comment: you mean if we create custom fields on a custom object which is created by managed package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Source: I do this all the time; last time was 5 minutes ago.